# error when AppKit framework added in iphone application

Tags: iphone, nsfilewrapper

i want to import  in my iphone application, but i know this framework is not available in iphone sdk,but i need to use NSfileWrapper class in this framework, is this class also available in UIKit or others framework available in iphone sdk, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, NSFileWrapper is not available on the iPhone. Simply adding a framework that doesn't exist on the iPhone also won't get you anything. Your application is very limited on the iPhone with regards to accessing files and you basically have to use the classes and methods provided by the Foundation framework for the iPhone.